# how to use 2 imeoption of soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, imeoptions

i want to show both because i have 3 edit text and in 2 second edit text i want to show both option on soft keyboard so that user can go to previous or next edit text, is there anyway to do this?
     here is my code

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etxtrunner"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtrunner"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtrunner"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/qrcode_img"
    android:background="@color/gray"
     android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:ems="10" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext|actionGo"
```

Comment: All should be working fine. Long tap the option button to show other options